# Facebook App - Get wall posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

Basically I have an idea for a Facebook Application that I wish to build.

I wondered if it is possible to get a user's wall posts, including likes and comments, and maybe even posts by other people on a users wall.

I do not have any previous experience programming Facebook Apps, but i'm a confident programmer and just wanted to make sure this is possible before I start learning, as I have not been able to find any useful information via Google.

If someone could just point me in the right direction and a yes/no answer, that would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

All of that is available via the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Note that you have to have the user grant your app specific permissions depending on what information you want to access.

Comment: Perfect, I'm not sure how I didn't come across this when searching Google :S Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easyest way is to get the posts feed:

https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=your_facebook_page_id&format=rss20

In case you know only the facebook url page and not the facebook page ID, just access the page below and you will see your ID printed on the first line:

https://graph.facebook.com/your_facebook_url